# Trying to run logistic (binary) regression in QGIS using 2 polygon layers, but unsure which tool to use

Tags: qgis, polygon, regression

I am trying to use a polygons layer A with continuous values as an independent variable and a polygons layer B with binary 1 and 0 values as the dependent variable in a logistic regression to see whether there is actually a strong statistical predictive influence of layer A determining the binary outcome of layer B. And so given that this is a GIS problem, I am trying to account for not only whether the polygons values in layer A have an influence on layer B, but also how proximity of layer A polygons to layer B polygons influences the binary outcome.

It seems like logistic regression is the way to do this, basically asking can out continuous independent variable determine a binary outcome?

For further clarification, here is an example of my research problem:

Each little orange spec represents a household that participated in my study. For each of these households I have an annual income value. The much bigger pink and blue polygons represent census tracts in a given city. Each of these census tract polygons contain a binary 1 (yes) and 0 (no) value representing whether or not that specific census tract has been designated by the local government body as educationally-disadvantaged. And so I want to find out, is there a spatially-weighted relationship between household income from my sampled households and whether the census tract is marked as educationally-disadvantaged? Such to the point that if I look at a household’s income I can be confident that that house very likely resides within a census tract marked as educationally-disadvantaged.

Here is what the polygons look like:
[image]

I see that in ArcGIS I would carry this out using the Geographically Weighted Regression (GWR) tool and selecting Binary (Logistic) as the model type. Though I am having some trouble finding an equivalent tool in QGIS, since there seem to be so many regression options within SAGA. Which QGIS tool and settings would be most appropriate for carrying out my specific regression problem?